# Excel Multiple Conditional Statements

Tags: excel

```
Hour  Daypart               From    To  Daypart Cluster 
-------------               -------------------------------
1     Overnight              6      10  Morning     
6     Morning                10     15  Midday  
15    Afternoon              15     19  Afternoon   
20    Evening                19     24  Evening     
8     Morning                24     6   Overnight
```

I need to assign a 'DayPart' grouping (in a separate column) to reflect the Daypart from a cross-reference table based on the hour.

For instance, if `Hour > 10, and hour < 15`, then cluster should be **"midday"**.

I am running into a problem when because I need to account for other dayparts.

So far my conditions in Excel result in False:

```
=IF(AND(H2>$O$2,H2>$P$2,$Q$2),IF(AND(H2>$O$3,H2<$P$3,$Q$3),IF(AND(H2>$O$4,H2<$P$4,$Q$4),AND(H2>$O$5,H2<$P$5,$Q$5))))
```

[image]

Comment: What is the second comma in your `AND` meant to represent?

Comment: changed the term 'cluster' to 'group' or 'grouping'; moved the cross-reference table away from the sample data; removed some narrative debris

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the *Overnight* to start at *0* and go to *6* then move that to the first row of the criteria.

I'll start with a nested set conditional statements. If you start with a single condition that no other can meet then progress through the possibilities you only need one condition for each *DayPart*. In the sample image below, I2 is,

```
=IF(H2<6, "Overnight", IF(H2<10, "Morning", IF(H2<15, "Midday", IF(H2<19, "Afternoon", "Evening"))))
```

As you can see, with a progressive condition where the subsequent condition can only be reached if the first is *False*, there is no need for the *To* hour at all.

If you want to use your cross-reference table, it needs to be reoriented slightly.

[image: DayPart Grouping]

With the *Overnight* changed to start at zero hour and moved to the top so that the starting hour is in an ascending order, a [VLOOKUP function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/vlookup-function-adceda66-30de-4f26-923b-7257939faa65) can be used to lookup the approximate match on the ascending starting hours. In the sample image above the formula in J2 is,

```
=VLOOKUP(H2, $O$2:$Q$6, 3, TRUE)
```

Fill down as necessary. As is common with nested *less than* or *greater than* conditions, there is some ambiguity between *less than* and/or *less than or equal to*. If the results are not exact, this should be an easy fix.